# android app install or run by web page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My app install or run.

```
intent:://open#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=packageName;....... end;
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".AActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
android:name=".BActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

A Activity runs B Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BActivity.class);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

webpage -- run app --> A Activity --> B Activity --> App Background move --> webpage --> run app --> B Activity Foreground

How can I run an A Activity when the app is a B Activity and is in the background?

Comment: on B activity on pause u can finish that activity by finish(); so every time you open your app from background ur activity A will start

Comment: It is not what I want. Activity B must be maintained except when run through a web page. I can call finish() and start A Activity  if I know that I have resume through the web page in the onResume of the B Activity. Is there a way?

Comment: u can send a bundle flag from activity A if it came from activity A u can send true if it is opening from somewhere else u can set default false ..

Comment: Can  I force my app to enter the A Activity when running the app on a web page?

Comment: u want to open A activity every time when app is launch from web page?

Comment: Yes, it is. I want to open A activity every time when app is launch from web page. It should also be when the APP is a B Activity and in the Background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170839/discussion-between-santoxme-and-juilcho).